# how create different bookmarks for two computers on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I have different sets of bookmarks - one is for work, and my work laptop.
Another bookmarks are for my home PC.
I dont want to have two accounts for that purpose - I just want an easy way to switch between 'bookmarks for work' and 'bookmarks for home'.

How can I do that ?
I tried adding another Person on my account - but it didnt let me sign in with my account - said that already another Person using that account.

Thanks for you're help

p.s maybe there's a recommended chrome extension that would solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

The best extension I know to do that is using Tabs, and bookmarking an entire group of tabs:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-my-tabs/dkcdcmananochmgmhgkhhmgegdnkgejl?hl=en